# Python MySQL connector 2 cursor

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Comecei agora com python e estou tentando isso:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  infos..
)

cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor2 = mydb.cursor()
query = ("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5")
cursor.execute(query)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row[1])
    var1 = "blabla"
    var2 = "blblbl"
    cursor2.execute("UPDATE table SET col1 = (%s), col2= (%s) WHERE col3= (%s)", (var1, var2, row[2]))

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
cursor2.close()
```

Mas continuo recebendo o erro:

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL
>   server during query

Eu pesquisei e achei que usando "buffered=True" resolveria o problema, mas não deu certo. Também tentei criar uma pool, mas quando executo no ponto de chegar no cursor2 aparece o erro:

> ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Não pode ser usado dois cursor pra mesma conexão? É isso?

Comment: Não conheço a lib especifica, então não sei se o termo "cursor" é o nativo do SQL ou alguma peculiaridade da lib. sugiro dar uma espiada se tem alguma função de query direta para usar nos updates (na verdade, em termos de mysql, nem precisaria de cursor para o select, bastaria ir dando fetch).

Comment: Tentei procurar sobre isso e encontrei esse esclarecimento sobre cursores no python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438325/3383534

Answer (score 1):

O que ocorre é que você está criando dois `cursor` e quando você fecha um deles, automaticamente fecha o outro. Pois trata-se da mesma conexão, diferenciando somente onde armazenou o `cursor`.

Fiz a adição do `dictionary=True`, pois sem ele, quando executar um `for` (para casos `fetchall()`) terá que informar a posição do valor com `index` e se sua tabela mudar as colunas de lugares o `index` vai trazer o valor errado, adicionando o `dictionary`, basta informar o nome da coluna, independentemente da posição que ele esteja

Faça o teste:

```py
import mysql.connector

mysql_cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
  infos..
)

mysql_cnx.autocommit = True
mysql_cnx_cursor = mysql_cnx.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)

query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5"
mysql_cnx_cursor.execute(query)

resultado_do_select = cursor.fetchall()

for row in resultado_do_select :
    print(row["NOME DA COLUNA 1"])
    var1 = "blabla"
    var2 = "blblbl"
    mysql_cnx_cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET col1 = (%s), col2= (%s) WHERE col3= (%s)", (var1, var2, row["NOME DA COLUNA 2"]))

cursor.close()
```

segue meu [crud_mysql.py](https://gist.github.com/WellingtonFonseca/cd112a9dcaf4df4a0891abd93bf405fb) pessoal

Answer (score 0):

A maioria das referências que achei, sugerem aumentar o limite padrão de algumas propriedades do mysql para esse erro não acontecer.

1. net_read_timeout;
2. max_allowed_packet;
3. connect_timeout;
4. wait_timeout
5. interactive_timeout

Como eu não tenho acesso ao mysql server e nem permissão para setar diretamente no python essas infos, tive que usar um "workaround" para burlar isso. Antes de cada execução de query eu tenho de "pingar" o servidor e reconectar caso tenha perdido a instância.

`conect.ping(reconnect=True, attempts=3, delay=2)` [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573794/3383534)